# How to get the number of elements in an int array?

Tags: c#, arrays

in this case I want to take the number of elements in the array , but the array  is dependent on user input

```
int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = first; i <= second; i++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        int[] some =new int [i];
        int c =some.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

I tried several options, but the output is still a list of the numbers divisible by 5 without remainder. How is right to do?

example: `first = 15`, `second = 50`. 
Expected output = `8`.

8 numbers divisible by 5 without remainder(15,20,25,30...50)

Comment: give some examples of input and expected result to make question more clear

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because you're paraphrasing for the sake of an example, but that `int[]` and `int c` is entirely redundant. You could just write `Console.WriteLine(i);` instead.

Comment: Of course it will list of number because you have for loop and then if condition (i % 5 == 0)

Comment: example: first = 15, second = 50. Expected output = 8. 8 numbers divisible by 5 without remainder(15,20,25,30...50)

Comment: you dont need an array. you just need a counter which increments inside `if`. create counter outside loop. increment inside loop. write result outside loop

Comment: Hi @stela, Do you want to display total number only or you want to display all numbers which are divisible by 5?

Comment: declare int count before the for loop as 0, inside %5==0 condition ,add count++. After For loop ends, print count.

Comment: To get how many numbers are divisible by 5 you don't need any array, and not even a loop. You don't have to create all the numbers to know how many there are. If the input is guaranteed to be divisible by 5 (as they are in your example), then all you need is `Console.WriteLine((second - first) / 5 + 1);`.

Comment: Hi @AbhilashPA , I need total number only

Comment: `var numbers = new List<int>();
            var count = 0;
            for (int i = first; i <= second; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    /// Increase count
                    count++;
                    /// Store the number which is divisible by 5 to an array
                    numbers.Add(i);
                    /// If you don't want to store number, just display it now
                    Console.WriteLine(i +", ");
                }
            }`

Comment: Hi @Guffa , not necessarily entered numbers are divisible  by 5 , this is just an example to show what I expect as an output

Comment: @stela: I expected that they might not be, that's why I specified that in the comment. Then you would first find the first and last number in the range that is divisible by 5: `first += 4 - ((first + 4) % 5); second -= second % 5;`.

Comment: Thanks @AbhilashPA ... made my day!!! it works perfect ;)

Comment: @stela Be happy always.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through the numbers and count how many you find that are divisible by 5:

```
int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = first; i <= second; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    cnt++;
  }
}
```

However, you dont have to generate the numbers to know how many there are. You can just calculate where the last number is (as that is easier than the first) and then calculate how many there are before that but after the first:

```
int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
second -= second % 5;
int cnt = (second - first) / 5 + 1;
```

For example for the input `3` and `11` you want to count the numbers `5` and `10`. The expression `11 % 5` gives `1`, so `second` becomes `10` (the last number). Then `second - first` is `7`, doing integer division with `5` gives `1`, and then add `1` gives `2`.

Comment: @stela: You forgot `second -= second % 5;`, that turns `14` into `10`, i.e. finds the last number divisible by 5 in the range. `(10 - 6) / 5 + 1 = 1`.

Comment: Ooops...@Guffa , try this: (14-6)/5 + 1= 2 If the interval does not begin and end with number divisible by 5?We have for example 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.